# Suggested approach for migrating content out of TeamSite into Drupal

Tags: drupal, teamsite

I'd like to hear your thoughts on the best approach for migrating content from TeamSite to Drupal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, not being versed in TeamSite, I will tell you how I approached it from Wordpress/proprietary sites before.

First, look to see if a module exists to do this. There is one that facilitates moving Wordpress to Drupal, for example.

If that doesn't exist, analyze the TeamSite system and try to correlate it with Drupal. What does a content/page consist of in TeamSite, does it categorize content. When you map the data out like that, you can easily script the data over into Drupal using the Drupal API.

You can also try advanced methods using the modules outlined in the comment here: http://drupal.org/node/636866

I've found that in the past it was quicker for me to look at the database and script the move.

Here is one tool that will take care of users for you, [User Import](http://drupal.org/project/user_import). All you have to do is upload a CSV file and map the fields into Drupal and it works. I am not sure how far along [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) is, but you can try that too.

Comment: Thanks - the Drupal side of things I'm pretty familiar with. Hoping to hear from someone experienced with TeamSite.

Answer (score 0):

For migrating content in general, I have found two modules extermely helpful: table wizard (http://drupal.org/project/tw) and migrate (http://drupal.org/project/migrate). There is a good article explaining what they do here: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-data-imports-migrate-and-table-wizard.

Comment: Thanks. I've used those modules successfully too. I'm more interested in specifics related to how TeamSite stores data. Being a proprietary system, there is not a lot of info out there on integrations, despite it being a popular enterprise application.

Answer (score 0):

Teamsite can create static html or jsp pages based on contents stored in lots of XML files created by each module. There is no easy way to migrate data other than to scrape the content using a robot.